# How to retrieve all datas in my firebase with different pushID?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Photo]

I want to retrieve all my datas and store each specific pushID into a button.

First question, how to get the keys of my push?
Second qustion, after getting the values, i want to store each ID into a button so i can update it. How?

Comment: Unless you've tried something and got stuck, it's unlikely we'll do a better job than the [Firebase documentation on working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data).

Answer (score 0):

could you get a JsonObject and then:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = responseBody.entrySet();
List<FeedRow> rowList = new LinkedList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {
   String key = entry.getKey()); 
   String value = responseBody.get(entry.getKey()).toString();
}
```

then save in a list.
with a recyclerview, 
1. add buttons with this list 
2. addOnClickListener in each button

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    database.getReference()
            .child("myfirstfirebaseproject-8f271")
            .child("all-user-dishes")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Log.v("KEY", "this is your key"+snapshot.getKey());
                        Log.v("VALUE", "this is your value"+snapshot.getValue());

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("all-user-dishes");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String dishName = ds.child("dishName").getValue(String.class);
            String dishPrice = ds.child("dishPrice").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", dishName + " / " + dishPrice);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Luncheeon Meat / 150
Fruit Salad / 50
Sardines / 80
```